# Is a question that can only be answered correctly by a small group of people a bad question?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, opinion-based

Recently I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29929654/why-doesnt-c-sharp-have-a-datetime-literal) on SO and it was quickly closed for being opinion based. One of the commenters mentioned that it could "*only be accurately answered by the designers*" of the language.

There are a lot of people registered in StackOverflow, and some of them *are* language designers or participate in language design decisions, like Eric Lippert for instance.

Is a question that can only be accurately answered by a very small subset of people on SO a bad question, i.e. one that should not be made on the site at all? To me, this makes no sense, because it is a valid question, someone knows the answer, and the answer is objective.

Today I found another question that, to me, is very similar to mine. It asks [why extension methods are not possible in nested classes in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443842/why-not-allow-extension-method-definition-in-nested-class). I stumbled on it by accident, and immediately related it to my own question, and wondered why it was not also closed for the same reasons that mine was.

Comment: Eric *used* to be a language designer.  He left that job over 3 years ago.

Comment: Just because they are a designer does not mean they were THE C# designer.

Comment: Are the downvoters downvoting me because they disagree with my reasoning, or because my question is not a good question?

Comment: Disagreeing, likely.  Voting on Meta works a bit differently.

Comment: Yup, Eric instantly forgot everything he knew about C# design.  Do focus on the [Help Center article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), the word *practical* is key.  What are you going to do differently once you get an answer?  As posted, surely nothing.  Do play on this, you could ask "Is there an issue with VB.NET date literals I should know about?" and noodle a bit about using literals a lot and noticing that C# does not support them.  Tag it [vb.net], not [c#] so you'll avoid fan votes, decent odds you'll get an answer.

Comment: Even if Eric saw your question, I'm willing to bet good money he will turn your question around and talk about the costs that come with implementing a feature.

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel: Such as http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A88656+design+implement+test

Comment: The same reason why every other possible thing hasn't been implemented in C#--because you have a limited number of resources to spend, and you must pick and choose what to spend it on. That answer is about as useless as you can get, and it perfectly answers the question. Therefore...

Comment: Seems it is important you ask the question, everybody is guessing at the wrong answer.

Comment: Related meta question by Eric himself: [Is miscategorization of obscure questions as “not real” a problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96310/is-miscategorization-of-obscure-questions-as-not-real-a-problem)

Comment: @Will I know this is a common response to some feature requests, but that's not a valid answer for all 'features'. I mentioned this in a comment, but it could be possible that it was not implemented in C# because it could introduce some bad behavior or bad practice, for example.

Comment: It would still be trivia, and not a practical, answerable programming question. I love trivia, believe me. But asking about trivia on SO is off topic. Has been for a long time. Sorry, but your argument brings nothing new to the table. Though I do appreciate the link to that other question.  VTC that as well.

Comment: [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172420/is-it-subjective-to-ask-about-why-something-wasnt-implemented-in-the-language) is also somewhat related to the kinds of questions being asked about. Oh look one of our favorite language designers thinks these are not good questions. It is not about obscurity, per se. It is about how questions of this type ("Why doesn't language X have feature Y") all have very similar answers that aren't really very satisfying ("Because they didn't think of/implement it").

Comment: The question about extension methods that you link to should have been closed as a duplicate. The original question you will note I answered as "the feature wasn't implemented because the language designers thought that its costs were higher than its benefits". Which I note is the same answer as to your question "why does C# not have date literals?"

Answer (score 9):

> Why doesn't [lang] have [feature]?

Those questions ask for one of these:

- [Word of God](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WordOfGod)
- Idle speculation

Unless there happens to be documented word of the designers rationale lieing around, or one of the designers stumbles over it and feels the need (or wish) to justify their decision, you'll only get the latter.
And unless the former happens fast, you will get the latter many times over, going in completely different directions, and with very little substance.
And that's why it's primarily opinion-based for sure.

There is a reason the latter question wasn't immediately shot down when posted:
It happened 3 years ago.

Comment: In my opinion, if you don't know the answer to something, you should not speculate, and instead refrain from answering to begin with. Answers should be answers, not guesses. I'd even argue that guesses could be better represented by comments. Am I completely off on this? And regarding the 3 years ago comment, did these rules change since then?

Comment: Yes, enforcement beame more stringent in many cases, and policies were changed over time, so iff you want to give examples of similar posts, try for recent ones. Don't be disappointed when they will simply be dealt with though. And saying "you should not speculate" to a question which begs for it simply doesn't fly. Which is why it is closed for opinion.

Comment: @julealgon: There's a certain practicality in close reasons. If a question *could* be answered correctly, but is highly likely to be answered incorrectly *instead*, it will usually be closed.

Comment: To add to Nathan's point: should the right person come across the question later and express interest in answering it objectively, they could make a case for reopening the question.

Comment: @julealgon You may wish that people not speculate and post answers with their guesses or opinions, but regardless of what you want, that's what people tend to do.  Whenever I see a question like this that's what happens in 95% of cases (the remaining being no answer at all).

Comment: @Servy fair enough. I know this could be another question entirely but... is it acceptable or even encouraged to answer questions when one is not sure it is the correct answer?

Comment: @Servy: To be fair, it's not just how the OP wants but how it should be. An objective question has objective answer(s), which is a fact. The fact (also) that people tend to pile on questions like this is simply unfortunate and real enough of a problem to warrant nipping in the bud.

Answer (score 5):

Not knowing much about C#, here's how I read your question title.

### Why doesn't [language] have [feature]?

That's pretty broad, isn't it?  The only people that could answer definitively would be the language designers, and we can't guarantee that this would get their attention enough to post a remark.

The reason that this is an issue boils down to more of a numbers game than anything else; there are substantially more C# developers eager to help you answer a question than there are language designers that have the free time to answer.  If someone that isn't qualified attempts to answer the question (and let's face it, someone most certainly *will*), then the answer you'd have would be incomplete at best.

The other question you link to (again, my naivety of C# taking over), reads like a nested class from Java, and someone coming over from Java to C# may be confused if they run into a scenario like that and have it not work (although again, I don't know C#, so I couldn't tell you if that's a fair question to ask or not).

Comment: I understand your point, but if I came from VB to C# I could also be confused too, since VB _has_ DateTime literals.

Comment: Also, you said "The only people that could answer definitively would be the language designers, and we can't guarantee that this would get their attention enough to post a remark.". That's what I'd like to know really and the core of my question here. Is it _bad_ that only very few people would know the answer at all, and that the people who know could not even be registered in SO at all (I wouldn't always know that someone knows the answer to any given question before posting)? Is it really that bad that a question like that could be unanswered for a long time or potentially forever?

Comment: I suppose I was being implicit as to the effect that this could have.  I'll clarify my stance.

Answer (score 5):

"*It can only be answered by the designers*," is a bit of a red herring. The real issue is that an answer to this question doesn't seem to have any practical benefit to anyone, as it's entirely a question about the history of the language. It's not a question about software development.

The only case in which "*Why doesn't this language have this feature?*" could be useful is when it asks for information fundamental to the language's approach for accomplishing things.

I'm not a C# programmer, so I can only guess, but the other question appears to be seeking an understanding of how extensions ought to be used generally, and particularly why they're not applicable in a particular context that seems like it ought to be valid. By contrast, your question asks about the syntactic sugar of datetime literals, which doesn't seem likely to reveal any deeper understanding of any C# features or patterns.

Comment: I asked the question mainly because I was assuming that having literal datetimes supported in the language would allow me to then have `const` datetimes, so I'd disagree with your last part, because allowing `const` datetimes would significantly change how one could write attribute constructors and would in turn be a lot more type safe and simple. Someone commented that having the literals support and enabling `const` were different things, but I wasn't aware of it initially. I hadn't thought about your first point though, that the answer would not benefit anyone. This is questionable IMHO.